# Decoding a list of base64 strings into png images using for loops is only creating one file (python3)

Tags: python, for-loop, image-processing, base64

I have a load of images that are currently encoded in base64. I am trying to decode them all in one go and print the output to individual files.

I am trying the code below, which results in no errors but, rather than outputting a different image for each string in the list, it outputs multiple files of the same image.

```
import base64
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

# images = ['List of base64 strings']

for i in range(len(images)):
      for b64_string in images:
          im = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(b64_string)))
          im.save(f"{i}.png",'PNG')
```

I am new to python / programming in general so I may be well off with what I am trying, but I am keen to learn where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easier way to get index values in python, you can use `enumerate`. It will give you the index of the element and the element, so you can just iterate into it and do it as you wish.

```
for i, b64_string in enumerate(images):
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(b64_string)))
    im.save(f"{i}.png",'PNG')
```

Link to documentation: [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Example from documentation:

```
>>> seasons = ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter']
>>> list(enumerate(seasons))
[(0, 'Spring'), (1, 'Summer'), (2, 'Fall'), (3, 'Winter')]
>>> list(enumerate(seasons, start=1))
[(1, 'Spring'), (2, 'Summer'), (3, 'Fall'), (4, 'Winter')]
```

Comment: That is brilliant thank you! Really good knowledge, I haven't come across that yet, did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the inner loop, because right now you're processing each image multiple times.

```
for i, image in enumerate(images):
      im = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(image)))
      im.save(f"{i}.png",'PNG')
```